# Pluggin' in Plugins

Tags: php, plugin

I'm currently working on an in-house project and a part of that project is this pretty standard plugin loader below.

There must be a way to avoid so many ugly looking `else` statements.

I'm kinda hitting a brick wall with getting better at "writing less to achieve the same thing".

How I can improve the code as I do think it's pretty clean, but I got this aching feeling that I've been missing a lot of "shorthanding" my code?

```
/**
 * Load plugins specified by the array $load, containing the leading filenames in the /src/plugins/ folder
 * All plugins must be proceeded with *.plugin.php where the asterisk is the name of the respective plugin
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @param array $load e.g: array("Users", "Products", "Pages")
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($load) {

    $this->plugin_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/PlugCMS/src/plugins";

    require_once($this->plugin_dir . "/Users.default.php"); // Included by default, and is required to gain access to the dashboard
    require_once($this->plugin_dir . "/Pages.default.php"); // You can remove this but you will need to remove the pageLoader.php mod_rewrite rule from .htaccess to get control of the front-end back.

    if (is_dir($this->plugin_dir)) {            
        if (is_array($load)) {

            $count = count($load);

            for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                $filename = $this->plugin_dir . "/" . $load[$i] . ".plugin.php";

                if (file_exists($filename)) {

                    if (@require_once($filename)) {
                        $this->load_output['active'][] = $load[$i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->load_output['failed'][] = $load[$i];
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    $this->load_output['failed'][] = $load[$i];
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->load_output['error'][] = "Error: $load must be an array";
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load_output['error'][] = "PlugCMS has detected the default plugin directory is missing ({$this->plugin_dir}). Please check the installation and try again..";
    }

}
```

Comment: Argh... seeing code that contains `@require_once` really makes my blood boil. Please don't use the `@` operator of death: if you see a warning/notice/error, FIX IT, don't silence it.

Comment: @Elias The default plugins stop on error, the user-defined ones are silences as it's not worth it causing the site to halt just because someone messed up a plugin, they can debug outside of the plugin loader.

Comment: I have changed it to `@include_once` too as suggested by @tim and @janos

Comment: That's not the point. The point is your use of `@`. If an include produces an error/warning/notice, then you should work out why it does so, and fix the root cause. Supressing the error doesn't fix the problem. Think of it as cleaning your house: you can wipe the dirt under the carpet so you don't see it, but it's still there; or you can get a vacuum cleaner and remove it entirely. The latter is the cleaner option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I think surely there must be a way to avoid so many ugly looking else statements.

Return early, for example:

```
if (is_dir($this->plugin_dir)) {
    $this->load_output['error'][] = "PlugCMS has detected the default plugin directory is missing ({$this->plugin_dir}). Please check the installation and try again..";
    return;
}
```

You can do the same for `is_array($load)`, and already you got rid of two levels of nesting.

You can also combine `file_exists($filename)` and `@require_once($filename)` to `file_exists($filename) && @require_once($filename)` to get rid of another level of nesting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm aware of return early but the opportunity is unfortunately quite rare, touché on combining the `file_exists()` and `require_once()`.

Would anyone have a reference URL with something similar to add to what Tim said; but not limited to? I've come up `NULL` on anything decent throughout my searches.

Comment: you have an extra Curly Brace in there??

Comment: @Zanderwar try searching for `reduce deeply nested if statements` (no reason to include a language, the principles are pretty much universal), there are quite a few results for it.

Answer (score 15):

> I'm aware of return early but the opportunity is unfortunately quite rare

Two levels removed as [@tim](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/49695/tim)'s suggestions, it's quite significant.
With his other suggestions applied too, the whole thing becomes quite a bit shorter:

```
if (!is_dir($this->plugin_dir)) {            
    $this->load_output['error'][] = "PlugCMS has detected the default plugin directory is missing ({$this->plugin_dir}). Please check the installation and try again..";
    return;
}
if (!is_array($load)) {
    $this->load_output['error'][] = "Error: $load must be an array";
    return;
}   

$count = count($load);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $filename = $this->plugin_dir . "/" . $load[$i] . ".plugin.php";

    if (file_exists($filename) && @require_once($filename)) {
        $this->load_output['active'][] = $load[$i];
    } else {
        $this->load_output['failed'][] = $load[$i];
    }
}
```

In addition,
I think you can replace this:

> ```
> if (file_exists($filename) && @require_once($filename)) {
> ```

With this:

```
if (@include_once($filename)) {
```

Because if the file doesn't exist, the `include_once` will fail anyway.

Originally I suggested `@require_once` there,
but that would be bad, as @tim has pointed out:

> As require_once will halt the script on failure, only using `if (@require_once($filename))` will not work (the script will stop completely, and the else statement will not be executed). So either the `file_exists` should be kept, or `include_once` should be used (this probably makes more sense, but might be a bit harder to read).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I feel it important to note that `include`, `require` and their respective `*_once` statements are *language constructs*, not functions. As such, you should stylistically avoid using brackets:

```
require_once $this->plugin_dir . "/Users.default.php";
```

It will work with them, but it's considered bad practice to use them.